# template class .How to implement this ?c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have to do this :

- Create a template class for renting any service.
- The `rentService(T service)` method should register the name of the person that rents the service.
- If `T` (the service that is being rented) is a `Car` then `rentService` should also validate if the person has a valid driver’s license.

I dont want you to write code for me but help me with some ideas how i should handle this.
I am thinking to create a template class `Car` with a vector of people .
So i will go through the vector of people and first with driver's license to rent it .But ,i should declare the license where ?? Or to create a class person?

Comment: What is the input data? How do you validate if a person has valid driver's license? Do you have this information for all persons or just for persons renting a car?

Comment: Where in the question are 'people' mentioned?  I think you're wandering off topic to think about how many people might be renting a service.  With most things I've rented, it's just me renting, sometimes there's an additional driver but that would appear to be out of the scope of the assignment.

Comment: Unrelated: A template for creating classes is usually called a _class template_, not a _template class_.

Comment: These are all details .. they want me to implement this how i want .I supposed that i need to use a vector of people/person becase they said rentService should register the name of a person that has a valid driver license.

Comment: I think you need to show your ideas in code. Making `Car` a class template sounds a bit odd though. What would the template parameters be?

Comment: I am new with these templates ,thats why i've asked you about this,because i was not sure that is correct.I will try to do something and if i have problems i will ask .

Answer (score 0):

you can use [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) and it looks somethig like this:

```
template<typename Event_Type>
class Renting
{
    bool rentService(T service)
    {
        if (typeid(service) == typeid(Car))
        {
            checkDriverLicense()
        { 
    }
}
```

C++ 17 version base on  Jarod42 comment

```
bool rentService(T service)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same<Car, T>::value)
    {
        checkDriverLicense()
    { 
}
```

or you can use template specialization as @keyoted suggest

```
template<typename Event_Type>
class Renting
{
    bool rentService(Event_Type service);
};

template<typename Event_Type>
bool Renting<Event_Type>::rentService(Event_Type service)
{
    // etc...
}

template<>
bool Renting<Car>::rentService(Car service)
{
    // This will only be callet when Event_Type == Car
    checkDriverLicense()

}
```

Comment: so if i have another 3 classes,like Books, House etc ,i can do this for every class,right?

Comment: yes, but only if the T is of type Car it will chack for license

Comment: `std::is_same<Car, T>::value` instead of `typeid`, and `if constexpr` since C++17.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for @yaodav would be

```cpp
template<typename Event_Type>
class Renting
{
    bool rentService(Event_Type service);
};

template<typename Event_Type>
bool Renting<Event_Type>::rentService(Event_Type service)
{
    // etc...
}

template<>
bool Renting<Car>::rentService(Car service)
{
    // This will only be callet when Event_Type == Car
    checkDriverLicense()

}
```